# Deleting alternate rows from the text file using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im doing a project where i have to read the datas from a .txt file and then insert each line into a table using query.

Now for example the contents of the text file would be

11111

1111x

22222

2222x

33333

3333x

and so on.

Now as you can see that the alternate row is almost repetitive so i would like to remove alternate rows so that the available data becomes

11111

22222

33333

and then process the rest of my codes.

Is there any way i can do that?

So far i have been using the Array list to get this

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("03122013114450.txt"), true))
        {

            string txtValues = sr.ReadToEnd();
            string[] txtValuesArray1 = Regex.Split(txtValues, "\r\n");



            ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
            foreach (string value in txtValuesArray1)
            {
                array.Add(value);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
            {
                if (array.Count % 2 != 0)
                    array.RemoveAt(i + 2);
                else
                    array.RemoveAt(i + 1);
            }
        }
```

The basic idea is to delete the alternate rows wether it be from the index of the arraylist of from the text file.

Comment: Is it correct that you always append one digit at the end compared to the original line, f.e. `111111` instead of `11111` or `222222` instead of `22222`?

Comment: what version of `.Net`, why use `ArrayList`?

Comment: Really sorry TimSchmelter it was my mistake while typing. I have edited the post again. Thanks for bringing it up in light.

Comment: Jodrell im using .net version 3.5. Does that really matter about the usage of the version.?

Comment: Older versions (<2.0?) did not have generic collections (like `List<T>`) and you had to use `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Vikneshwar, yes, for instance you won't be able to use `yield return`, You should be using a generic string collection, not `ArrayList`, it is obselete.

Comment: @Jodrell, i understand that from your explanation. But i haven't been in this kind of scenario before. So couldnt find a way to do it except using array list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another optimization:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("03122013114450.txt"), true))
{
    var line = sr.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        // Do stuff here. Add to the list, maybe?

        if (sr.ReadLine()!= null) //read the next line and ignore it.
            line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If you want to ignore the odd line instead of the even lines, move the `line = sr.ReadLine();` from the end to the beginning of the while-loop

Comment: You'll need to test for `sr.EndOfStream` between `sr.ReadLine()` invocations, in case the file isn't an even number of lines.

Answer (score 2):

A quick optimization,

```
static IEnumerable<string> OddLines(string path)
{
    var flipper = true;

    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path))
    {
        if (flipper) yield return line;
        flipper = !flipper;
    }
}
```

which you can use like this,

```
var oddlines = OddLines(Server.MapPath("03122013114450.txt"));
```

---

or, even simpler

```
var oddlines = File.ReadLines(Server.MapPath("03122013114450.txt"))
                   .Where((l, i) => i % 2 == 0);
```

Comment: Your last example returns lines 1, 3, 5, etc. That's opposite of your `OddLines` method, which returns lines 0, 2, 4, etc. Also, consider using `File.ReadLines` rather than `File.ReadAllLines`.

Comment: @JimMischel thanks for spotting the inconsistency. The choice of `ReadLines` or `ReadAllLines` is a important consideration and would depend on whether you are concerned about memory usage or leaving the file open while you iterate the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried this with LINQ

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("your_file_name");
var result = lines.Where((s, idx) => idx % 2 == 0);
```

of course, if your file is very big, then you need to work line by line and skip the not required lines while reading

Comment: like you mentioned that i have to skip the lines that i do not need while reading. Can you provide any kind of guidance.?

Comment: The 3 other answers here skip the lines while reading the file.

Answer (score 1):

What you typically want to do is read one line of the file at a time, rather than buffer all the data on disk into memory. Think if it were a 2GB text file (not that unusual a problem to have) - you're waiting on 2GBs to load first before you even begin to process it.

```
ulong count = 0;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("03122013114450.txt"), true))
{
   while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
       count++;
       String line = sr.ReadLine();
       if ((count % 2) == 0) {
           // do additional processing here
           // like insert row into database
       }
    }
}
```

(My C# is rusty.)